# Word VBA move selection to next and previous review comments in comments pane

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write VBA and C# code to move the cursor among review comments in Word. I want to do this to provide voice accessibility commands to work with review comments. Some of the behaviors are anomalous and I wonder if I have the right code.

I am working with a normal word document with several paragraphs in it and four review comments visible in the comment review pane. The comments are labeled 1, 2, 3, 4. If my cursor is in the word document, the following snippets will successfully move the insertion point to the beginning of the commented text fields in the main Word document body, as expected.

```
sel.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToComment, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToNext);
sel.GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToComment, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToPrevious);
```

However, if the insertion point is actually within the comment itself, only the “wdGotoNext” code moves the insertion point to the inside of the next review comment. The “wdGoToPrevious” code does not move the insertion point out of the current comment body.

In addition, if I use the following snippet to delete the review comment containing the selection in the comment body, Word moves the selection into the comment body of the following review comment. But I can’t find a syntax to delete a comment and move the selection into the previous comment body.

```
sel.Comments[1].Delete();
```

Is there a different API or code syntax that I should be using to move the cursor into and out of the comment bodies themselves? I would like to have code snippets to move the cursor up and down within the Word document mainstory as well as move the cursor up and down inside the comment bodies in the comment pane. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain why you want to select the comments. Selecting anything in Word is rarely necessary when processing content in code, and is highly inefficient.

Comment: Done. I want to do this to provide voice accessibility commands to work with review comments.

Comment: PS. It's not that I want to "select" the text in the comments. I would use a Range if that were possible. I just use the selection because ```selection.Comments[x]``` tells me where the cursor focus is. I do know about inefficient use of the Selection, if that helps any. :-)

Comment: Most of the people that give answers here will try to steer you away from using `Selection`. That's why you need to be super clear about exactly what you're attempting to achieve. FWIW, testing in VBA both `GoToNext` and `GoToPrevious` work fine (O365 Win10), regardless of where the cursor is. Because you know that `Delete` will cause the next comment to be selected you could follow it with  `GoToPrevious` to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: The `Comment` object does provide you with several `Range` objects. `Range` is the comment itself; `Reference` is the start of the marked text in the document; and `Scope` is the range of the full marked text in the document. `Index` will always return the index number relative to the `Document.Comments` collection, so if you keep track of that you can move back and forth. Does that help?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for that information. FWIW, I made VBA subs (O365,win10) containing one Selection.Goto statement in each, and they work the same as the C# code. In a one-word review comment, with the selection at the end of the single word, successive wdGotoPrevious operations move the selection to the start of the one-word comment; to the start of the Reference marked text for the comment; and the Reference start of the marked text in the previous comment. I would like the selection to move to the start of the previous review comment on the first jump. Continued...

Comment: I was thinking I should search the doc.Comments[x] collection to find the one containing the selection (let's call it 'current', then activate the doc.Comments[current-1] comment somehow. That might do it. (There is no selection.information[wdCommentIndex] value.)

Comment: The only time I see the behavior you describe with `wdGotoPrevious` is when the cursor is in the first comment in the document.